# Remove \cite{ref1} output of [1]

Tags: bibtex

I added the references using `BibFile1.bib` and in `BibFile1.bib` include the reference label as `ref1`. My TeX document code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\begin{document}
\cite{ref1}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{BibFile1}
\end{document}
```

In out put first print [1] and then reference information. I need to delete this [1]. What I need to do?

Comment: `\nocite{ref1}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print the bibliography without explicitly citing the references, then you can use `\nocite{*}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{BibFile1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or, for chosen items, `\nocite{ref1,ref2,...}`